# Является ли получение указателя из ссылки noexcept?

Tags: c++, исключения

Можно ли объявлять `noexcept` функцию, которая получает указатель из ссылки. Например, такую функцию:

```
template<typename T>
const void * void_pointer(const T & object) noexcept
{
    return &object;
}
```

Comment: Преобразование скалярных типов и builtin-операторы — это в любом случае noexcept.

Comment: @bipll Вы знаете что такое перезагрузка операторов?

Comment: наполовину С, на половину С++, в одной простой функции. Возвращайте T* a не void*

Comment: @ARHovsepyan а еще лучше `std::shared_ptr<std::any>`

Comment: @Andrio Skur , не лучше,  результат должен быть таким, каким  мы хотим чтоб он был...

Comment: Что вы хотите получить концептуально в случае если `T` будет каким-то "умным указателем"?

Comment: @AndrioSkur Нет, вот про перезагрузку их я первый раз слышу. Это если с первого раза не вышло применить оператор, надо еще раз попробовать, обязательно получится? :D

Comment: Насколько я знаю, получение адреса имеет приоритет перед перегруженным пользовательским оператором, и  мой ответ ДА, является noexcept

Comment: @ARHovsepyan какой еще приоритет? Приоритет операторов не меняется при перегрузке. Да и смысл тогда в такой перегрузке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Можно ли объявлять `noexcept` функцию которая...

Любую функцию можно сделать `noexcept`.

Смысл `noexcept` функций в том, что попытка выбросить исключение из них вызывает `std::terminate`.

---

Если на самом деле вам интересно, может ли оператор взятия адреса выбросить исключение, то ответ - нет, не может. Если он не перегружен, конечно.

Answer (score 1):

Ссылка обязана указывать на какой-либо существующий объект, таким образом адрес не может быть `nullptr` и никаких проблем я тут не вижу. Кроме одной - перегруженный оператор `&` для используемого типа. В таком случае следует использовать [`std::addressof`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/addressof/). И если пройтись по ссылке можно как раз увидеть, что эта функция объявлена как `noexcept`, т.е. по сути то же самое, что и в вопросе. Получается сам рукописный шаблон в предложенном виде как бы и не нужен вовсе.

Однако, если под типом `T` придёт некий "умный указатель" (у которого как раз перегружен оператор взятия адреса) и вы хотите получить адрес целевого объекта, а не самого "умного указателя", то нужно использовать оператор [`noexcept`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept), который сделает шаблон более гибким:

```
template<typename T>
const void* void_pointer(const T& object) noexcept(noexcept(&object)) { ...
```

Ну и как сказано в ответе @HolyBlackCat `noexcept` не порождает невалидного кода, он лишь приводит к вызову `std::terminate` в случае, когда функция не выполнила возложенных на неё обязательств.

Comment: Чо за бредовая функция `std::addressof` ? Она ж сломает логику классов которые перезагружают `&`?

Comment: @AndrioSkur она для того и нужна, чтобы исключить влияние таких перегрузок.

Comment: Ну а если у меня есть класс который реализует логику умного указателя?

Comment: @AndrioSkur зависит, конечно, от намерений программиста, хотите ли вы получить адрес целевого объекта или самого "умного указателя". Если нужно учитывать возможную перегрузку, то нужно использовать оператор `noexcept` (как указал bipll в комментарии к вашему ответу).

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не являеться. Оператор `&` может быть перезагружен в пользовательскую функцию которая может кидаться исключениями

Comment: Можно `noexcept(noexcept(&object))` >_>

Comment: @bipll `object&` может кинуть вам исключение. Если уверены в обратном дайте мне ссылку на онлайн компилятор с доказательным кодом

Comment: @AndrioSkur, `noexcept(expression)` - это [невычисляемый](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept) контекст. [Тест](https://wandbox.org/permlink/db3vnvvMTHcIiK33)